# How to identify where in a list a certain letter is?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and trying to create hangman. I have created a list, but I can not figure out how to identify where in the list the users guess is. For instance, if the word is "yes", and the user guesses "y", the output is "correct". What I am striving for is "Y _ _".

Answer (score 0):

Just do a for loop with `enumerate()` to notate the indeces of the correct letters guessed to match with the user's guesses.

```
user_guesses = ['_', '_', '_']
answer = ['Y', 'e', 's']
while '_' in user_guesses:
    user_guess = input('Guess a letter: ')
    correct = False
    for i, letter in enumerate(answer):
        if letter == user_guess:
            correct = True
            user_guesses[i] = letter
    if correct:
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')
    print(*user_guesses)
```

Comment: Why not just `while '_' in user_guesses:` rather than `while (user_guesses.__contains__("_")):`?

Comment: Yes, much more readable.